# I am trying to add data from word doc to access database but it give me operator missing syntax

Tags: c#

I am reading word file and add data after it find Favour. Just wont to add data after favour. First record using this code added perfect record but second time it give Syntax error(operator missing). Please help me to correctly add all records

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\juilee Raut\Downloads\ITCL-CAES 1 (1).docx");
        doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
        doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
        IDataObject da = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        string text = da.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        richTextBox1.Text = text;

        string data = string.Empty;
        string[] data1 = richTextBox1.Lines;

        List<string> Info = new List<string>();

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int m = 0;
        while (i < data1.Length)
        {
            if (data1[i].StartsWith("FAVOUR:"))
            {
                j++;
                if (m == 0)
                {
                    data = data + data1[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;                           
                    string inf = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Info.ToArray());
                    con.Open();
                    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into AllData(FullJud) VALUES('" + inf + "')";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    Info.Clear();
                    inf = string.Empty;                         
                    m = 1;
                }                       
            }                   
            else
            {
                m = 0;
                if (data1[i] != "")
                {                          
                    if (data1[i].EndsWith("2017") && data1[i].Length == 10 || data1[i].EndsWith("2016") && data1[i].Length == 10)
                    {
                        data = data + data1[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "##ln##" + Environment.NewLine;
                        Info.Add(data1[i]);
                        Info.Add("##ln##");
                    }
                    else if(data1[i].StartsWith("SECTION:") || data1[i].StartsWith("Section:") || data1[i].StartsWith("SECTION-") || data1[i].Contains("SUBJECT:") || data1[i].StartsWith("Subject:") || data1[i].StartsWith("SUBJECT-") || data1[i].StartsWith("SUBJECTS:"))
                    {
                        data = data + data1[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;                              
                    }
                    else if(data1[i].EndsWith("Respondent.") || data1[i].EndsWith("Petitioner.") || data1[i].EndsWith("Appellant.") || data1[i].EndsWith("Appellant") || data1[i].EndsWith("Respondent") || data1[i].EndsWith("Counsel,"))
                    {
                        data = data + data1[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data = data + data1[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                        Info.Add(data1[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''391 ITR 382 (BOM): 88 TAXMANN.COM 556\r\nHIGH COURT OF BOMBAY \r\nM.S. SANKLECHA AND A.K. MENON, JJ.\r\nMalay N. Sanghvi v/s. Income Tax Officer\r\nIT APPEAL NO. 1342 OF 2014\r\n31.01.2017\r\n##ln##\r\nSection 80-IB of the Income-tax Act, 1961 - Deductions - Profits a'."

Comment: Maybe copy/paste the real error message you get. Also note that your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Last but not least, double-check your `inf` initialization

Comment: Ho sweet little [bobby table](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''391 ITR 382 (BOM): 88 TAXMANN.COM 556\r\nHIGH COURT OF BOMBAY \r\nM.S. SANKLECHA AND A.K. MENON, JJ.\r\nMalay N. Sanghvi v/s. Income Tax Officer\r\nIT APPEAL NO. 1342 OF 2014\r\n31.01.2017\r\n##ln##\r\nSection 80-IB of the Income-tax Act, 1961 - Deductions - Profits a'."

Comment: Please edit your post to include that in your question.

Comment: Please set a breakpoint at the line `con.Open();` and copy/paste the exact content of `inf` right before the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else
                            {
                                data.Replace("'", "/");
                                data1[i] = data1[i].Replace("'","/");
                                Info.Add(data1[i]);
                                data = data + data1[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                            }
```

In else part I just replace the ' to / and my problem is solve

Comment: Note that `data.Replace("'","/");` is useless here

Comment: Any reason you switched accepted answer two weeks later?

Answer (score 1):

What if `Info` contains several values, let's say:

```
Info = { "value1", "value2" }
```

Then, `inf` would be:

```
inf = "value1\r\nvalue2"
```

Therefore, `cmd.CommandText` would be:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into AllData(FullJud) VALUES('value1\r\nvalue2')";
```

and I'm quite sure this is not the wanted behaviour.

---

**Edit**

What if one value in `Info` contained a `'` character?

```
Info = { "val'ue" }
```

Then, `inf` would be:

```
inf = "val'ue"
```

Therefore, `cmd.CommandText` would be:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into AllData(FullJud) VALUES('val'ue')";
// SQL won't understand that part --------------------------|||
```

and that's where you get an error.

---

Moreover, what if `Info` had the following value instead:

```
Info = { "value1');DROP TABLE [anytable];--" }
```

That's typical SQL Injection.

---

Some questions/comments:

- What is `j` used for?
- What is the purpose of `inf = string.Empty;`? It is a local variable and will be garbage collected.
- What is the purpose of `data`? Will you even use it at some point?
- You are using a `while` loop when you could be using a `for(int i=0;i<data1.Length;i++)` loop.
- What if `data1` contains two consecutive strings starting with `"FAVOUR:"`?  Why would you insert only the first one, and not the second one?

Comment: Every records contain "FAVOUR:" at the end of that record and after "FAVOUR:" new records are started. data1 can store all the line from richtext box  and every time i am save data in strind data

Comment: Is there an apostrophe after `1961 - Deductions - Profits a` in your file?

Comment: Yes it contains aspstrophe

Comment: Well, check the ***Edit*** part of my answer and you'll understand what's your problem

Comment: @Juilee then why did you say otherwise yesterday?

Comment: Thank you Rafalon for your help i understand my mistake your answer help me to improve my code